# How to make model not too dependent on one variable?

Tags: dataset, categorical-data, apache-spark

Let's suppose I have a generic model:

```
Variable A | Variable B | Variable C | Variable D
```

`Variable D`is a categorical variable. ( for example models of cars - and the dataset on which I trained my model only has models up to year 2020 )

I know for sure that `Variable A | Variable B | Variable C` are always present, however `Variable D` can be missing  (if for example I am using models of cars from 2021).

My questions are:

1. If I cannot use data from 2021, how safe is it to use `Variable D` in my predictions?
2. Could I just randomly assign a value to `Variable D` when it is missing?
3. Is it possible that the model may become too reliant on `Variable D` and by randomly assigning values I might introduce bias?
4. Should I just drop `Variable D`, or just the rows without an associated category in the data on which my model has been trained?

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answers to all your questions really depend on what `Variable D` is. Based on your description it does seem like your model would be too dependent on `Variable D` and would not generalize.

I'll be using the car model example you have mentioned to explain my answer.

Let us consider a model which predicts `Car Price` based on car features. The dataset would be as follows:

[image]

Here you **should not use** `Car Model` as a feature as:

1. `Car Model` is a direct indicator of price. The model will just learn
   the mapping `Car Model` -> `Price` and doesn't learn any other
   features.
2. For future cases `Car Model` does not help
   prediction.

Consider a **new car** for which your model has to find the price. You'll have the following data:

[image]

Since your model hasn't seen **audi 100ls** it would make a very bad prediction.

You need to ask the following questions to help you decide what to do:

1. Will the variable be available during real-time prediction. If not,
   then do not make use of it during training.
2. If it is available, does it help prediction? Eg: A new car model's name does not help you determine car price, but other features like `fueltype`, `doornumber`, `mileage` etc. do help.
3. If the variable is both available and helps prediction in real-time , you can try **imputing missing values.**